# Is there a way to change LDAP password without having "unicodePwd" attribute

Tags: java, ldap

In my `LDAP` directory I don't have attribute called `unicodePwd`.

All I have us `userPassword`.

I wrote java to change userPassword attribute. However, it is storing it as plain text.
For example,
if I want my new password to be `newpassword`,

LDAP stores it as `newpassword` and it doesn't hash it.

I can't authenticate with this password once it is changed.

Part of my code where I am doing this:

```
String quotedPassword = "\"" + newPassword + "\"";
            byte[] newUnicodePassword = quotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

            //String newpass = new String(pwdArray, "UTF8");
            mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userPassword", newUnicodePassword));

            // Perform the update
            ctx.modifyAttributes(userName, mods);
```

I changed this code so it passes hashed password, but it is still not authenticating...

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(newPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));

            byte byteData[] = md.digest();

            //convert the byte to hex format method 1
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
             sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }

            //String newpass = new String(pwdArray, "UTF8");
            mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userPassword", sb.toString()));

            // Perform the update
            ctx.modifyAttributes(userName, mods);
```

Comment: Hashing the password yourself is definitely wrong. The server should do that. Which server is it? If it's OpenLDAP, you need to configure it to hash passwords in slapd.conf or slapd.d. Or try encoding it as UTF-8.

Comment: How can I tell whether it is OpenLDAP or not?

Comment: You don't know what LDAP server you're running? If there is a `slapd.exe` running, or if you have an `OpenLDAP` directory somewhere, or a `slapd.conf` file or `slapd.d` directory, it's OpenLDAP. If you can't access the server host ask the admin.

Comment: @EJP It's OpenLDAP. I asked my dba. He told me to send him a list of instructions on what needs to be done. Imagine that :) So now I have to read how to configure LDAP. Maybe I should be a dba :)

Comment: OK well look up *man slapd.conf* and *man slapo-policy,* assuming you're using the password policy overlay, which you should be.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a LDAP extended operation to do that so the server will handle it correctly, for details : http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3062.txt